# Why cast to a byte and then immediately back to an int?

Tags: c#, casting, colors, refactoring, rgb

Found this code:

`this.message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));`

Why not just do this?

`this.message.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(64, 64, 64);`

Found it in the designer code in Visual Studio.

Comment: The designer code is isn't meant to be modified. It's automatically created, which is how it ends up full of interesting syntax like this ;-)

Comment: Maybe the coder was an old Lisp programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's simply to force all the values into a specified range, like `0..255`, regardless of their initial values.

Unnecessary if you're controlling the constants (like a hard-coded `64`) but it may be that this code is generated dynamically from data that *isn't* so controlled (like a text entry box in a dialog, or if the designer lets you input values like 9999 but wants to coerce them back to a valid range).

Answer (score 0):

Only guess would be that they wanted the application to throw an error if a number greater than 255 was added?  You know the wonderful designer errors..